# Showing aggregated data at Manager's geography level in a parent child dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

Stuck with the following problem. Reported it in MSDN forum as well but no reply yet. Any help from your side?

I have `DimEmployee` dimension which has *parent child relationship* (`between ManagerID & EmployeeID`)

```
------------------------------------------------------------ 
EmployeeID  ManagerID   GeographyID Othe columns
------------------------------------------------------------
1              1                      G1    
2              1                      G2    
3              2                      G3    
4              4                      G4    
5              4                      G5
```

This dimension has been connected to `FactSales` using **EmployeeID**

```
----------------------
EmployeeID  Sales
----------------------
1            100
2            150
3            80
4            50
5            60
```

There is one more dimension called `DimGeography` which has reference relationship with **FactSales** through **GeographyID** column of `DimEmployee`

```
 ----------------------------------
    GeographyID GeoName
    ---------------------------------
    G1          Abc
    G2          Xyz
```

Now I have to rollup all subordinates data and show it under Manger’s geography as shown below

```
ABC (G1)                              330 (100+150+80)
Xyz (G2)                               110 (50+60)
```

I am able to show data at MangerID level data but unable to do so at Manager’s Geography level.
How do I solve this problem using MDX?"

Comment: Could you update your question posting the MDX you have so far ("I am able to show data at MangerID level")?

Answer (score 0):

My answer seems very simple, so perhaps I have not fully understood the problem?

```
SELECT
{[DimGeography].defaultMember.members} ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[whatever]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Sales]
```

I will try to refine my answer if it does not give you the expected results.

Comment: Hi Magnus, This query will not give correct answer. What I am expecting is showing data at managers geography level. For example if I select Manager "1" who belongs to geography "G1", his and all his subordinates (in our case 2 &3) sales should be rolled up and show under "1"'s geography, i.e., G1 = 100 (of EmployeeID 1)+ 150 (of EmployeeID 2)+ 80 (of EmployeeID 3) = 330.

Comment: I think I need to see the hierarchy of your DimGeography dimension. Does it break the top level into G1, G2, G3? With each of those containing one or more managers? And each of those managers having one or more employees?